# How to make a script that will generate a url by adding the input provided in form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a javascript that will redirect to the url that will be generated by adding the input provided in form and the main url.

For example ,
If the user puts 'Hello' inside the textbox
Then it should redirect it to 'https://example.domain/Hello'
And if he puts Bye then it should redirect it to 'https://example.domain/Bye'

Comment: I am not getting what do you mean by first part of the input?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+change+url+from+form+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply grab the value of the textinput and append it to your baseurl

```
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input");
let newURL = 'https://example.domain/' + inputBox.value;
```